# Passing data from Props to data in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class ="container bordered">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
  <CommitChart :data="chartOptions"></Commitchart>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import CommitChart from './CommitChart';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        labels:  ['pizza', 'lasagne', 'Cheese'],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3],
          backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(10, 158, 193, 1)',
                'rgba(116, 139, 153, 1)',
                'rgba(43, 94, 162, 1)',

            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(44, 64, 76, 1)',
              'rgba(44, 64, 76, 1)',
              'rgba(44, 64, 76, 1)',

            ],
            borderWidth: 3
        }],
    },
    };
  },
  components: { CommitChart },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

as you can see, this component is effectively a wrapper for another component which is  commitChart. Commit chart takes a json object of chartOptions. I don't want the other components to change anything but the labels and data, so I therefore would like to pass label and data as props and use these in data.

i tried adding these as props to this component and then in data, assigning them, something like this:

```
    props: 
['label']
```

and then in data:

```
label: labels
```

however this doesn't work

Any suggestions how i may achieve this?

Comment: Thanks but that's not my question, <CommitChart></CommitChart> renders fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to modify just a few of the options in your `chartOptions` object and pass them as to your `CommitChart` component.

```
export default {
  props:["label","data"],
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {...},
    }
  },
  computed:{
    commitChartOptions(){
      let localOptions = Object.assign({}, this.chartOptions)
      localOptions.datasets[0].label = this.label;
      localOptions.datasets[0].data = this.data;
      return localOptions;
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your template, use the `commitChartOptions` computed.

```
<CommitChart :data="commitChartOptions"></Commitchart>
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MmKEoN?editors=1010) demonstrating the concept.

Answer (score 8):

```
export default {
  props: ['label'],
  data () {
    return {
      anotherLabel: this.label, // you cannot use the same name as declared for props
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the latest version of Vue.js, you **can** use same name as declared as props. It should work.

Comment: @Kazmi please specify latest version number in your comment. It might useful for readers

Answer (score 1):

let assume:
`labels` is data and
`label` is props

then use this to copy:

```
this.labels = { ...this.label };
```

Answer (score -5):

Props are declared like this:

```
props: ['label']
```

not

```
props: {label}
```

here is working fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mroowu5z/)

Comment: The counter agrument could be used nowdays, props are more likely to be assigned to a object so they can be set with default values and types and such.